# how can a method be both overridable and used as a callback in coffeescript

Tags: inheritance, methods, callback, coffeescript

I'd like to create a class with a method that can be overridden by subclasses but can also be used as a callback. It seems I can only get the desired behavior in one or the other situation. Here's an example:

```
class Parent
    constructor: () ->
        @foo = "foo"

    fooNotAlwaysDefined: () ->
        console.log("In parent.fooNotAlwaysDefined, @foo:#{@foo}")

    childNotCalled: () =>
        console.log("In parent.childNotCalled, @foo:#{@foo}")

class Child extends Parent
    fooNotAlwaysDefined: () ->
        console.log("In child.fooNotAlwaysDefined, @foo:#{@foo}")

    childNotCalled: () ->
        console.log("In child.childNotCalled, @foo:#{@foo}")

c = new Child()
c.fooNotAlwaysDefined()
c.childNotCalled()
process.nextTick(c.fooNotAlwaysDefined)
process.nextTick(c.childNotCalled)
```

What I want is for the child function to be called and @foo to be in scope in both uses (c. and as a callback). Here's the output I get:

> In child.fooNotAlwaysDefined, @foo:foo
>
> In parent.childNotCalled, @foo:foo
>
> In child.fooNotAlwaysDefined, @foo:undefined
>
> In parent.childNotCalled, @foo:foo

The best workaround I've found is that I can wrap fooNotAlwaysDefined inside an anonymous function that's given to process.nextTick, but that's less than ideal.

```
process.nextTick(() -> c.fooNotAlwaysDefined())
```

> In child.fooNotAlwaysDefined, @foo:foo

Is there a way to structure the classes so I get the behavior I desire?

EDIT:
Answer:
The summary of the very helpful comments below is that the behavior seen with childNotCalled is a bug. I'll note that I'm seeing this behavior in 1.6.1, so while it might have been improved, it doesn't solve this issue.

Second EDIT:
The problem seems to have been resolved completely in 1.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic problem of `this` not being bound correctly. Two possible solutions, in addition to the one you already found:

You could define `childNotCalled` with a fat arrow as well.

Meh, kinda gross. Fat arrowed methods are kind of a code smell, as they "usually work" but allow you to be lazy and not think about the value of `this`. A cleaner way:

```
process.nextTick child.fooNotAlwaysDefined.bind(child)
```

This is *roughly* equivalent to wrapping it an anonymous function, but more declarative and will work even if you reassign the `child` variable to something else. It returns a new instance of `fooNotAlwaysDefined` with `this` bound to `child`, so that when it's executed on the next tick it will have the correct `this`.

This is very similar to what declaring a method with a fat arrow is doing, it just makes it more explicit, efficient, and easier to understand (since you can see from that line of code that it's doing the right thing, instead of having to check the definition of the method to ensure correctness).

The fact that a fat arrow in the superclass will override the child method's implementation unless they also use a fat arrow is another thing that makes them unappealing to me (check the compiled code to see why this is. It's the only way to do it and there's no way around it (except forbidding fat arrow methods), but it's not what you'd expect). That is a feature of CoffeeScript I feel we would be better without.

Comment: Actually, using a fat arrow in the child method will *not* work.  The parent constructor is called *after* the child constructor, meaning that the parent method is ultimately the one bound and saved onto the object.

Comment: @cspotcode Wow, you're right. I assumed CoffeeScript would do, you know, the reasonable thing. Ass out of me. Is there any reason not to consider this behavior a bug in the CoffeeScript compiler? That is to say, is there any scenario where this behavior would be desirable?

Comment: @cspotcode Looks like this bug was introduced with 1.6.0, kind of fixed but not really in 1.6.1, and will be fixed properly in the next release. Phew. https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2781

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks!  I'm not a regular CoffeeScript programmer so I'd assumed that was intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the situation that Underscore's `bindAll` method is designed for.  It binds a set of methods onto `this` so that they can be used as callbacks.  Also, it plays nice with inheritance, something that seems to fail with CoffeeScript's fat arrow syntax.

http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll

If you don't want to use Underscore or LoDash, you can do it yourself by adding the following to `Parent`'s constructor:

```
for methodName in ['fooNotAlwaysDefined', 'childNotCalled']
    @[methodName] = do(method = @[methodName]) =>
        => method.apply @, arguments
```

Using Underscore's `bindAll` method is cleaner:

```
_.bindAll @, 'fooNotAlwaysDefined', 'childNotCalled'
```

Or if you're not worried about compatibility with older browsers (seems like you're running in Node), you can assume that functions have the built-in `bind` method:

```
@fooNotAlwaysDefined = @fooNotAlwaysDefined.bind @
@childNotCalled = @childNotCalled.bind @
```